# What do you call this object?

Tags: meaning, word-request, vocabulary, image-identification

What do you call this kitchen appliance?

[image]

It is to make banana with milk. I would appreciate if you give me a link of how to use it too :)

Comment: What is it called in your language? Unless it is clear to us what it is, this really is not a language question. You might ask on [***Seasoned Advice SE***](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/) though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like it may be missing the end piece, but if it is what I think it is, you can call it either a "wand mixer" or an "immersion blender." (because you *immerse* it in the thing you're blending) See [these Google results](https://www.google.com/search?q=wand%20mixer&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

It's used as an alternative to a regular "[mixer](http://www.amazon.com/mixers/b?ie=UTF8&node=289929)" which has a separate bowl & different kinds of beater you can attach (for mixing dough for cakes, bread, etc) ... Or as an alternative to a regular "[blender](https://www.google.com/search?q=blender&tbm=isch)" which you use to make mixed drinks like margaritas :)

...By the way, "stuff" refers to something plural - you should instead ask "what do you call this [thing]?"

Comment: I edited and removed "stuff" from the title before reading your answer. I don't think it effects your answer in any way though.